# 530,5.7.0SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required

Tags: php, authentication, postfix, mail, smtp

#### PHP Mail error with the message:

```
530,5.7.0SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed Detail: Authentication Required
```

#### Following are the key sections of my PHP Script.

```php
new PHPMailer(true)
Host as 'smtp.gmail.com'
SetFrom('MyUsername-Of-Ubuntu-Login@mail.theDomainCreatedInPostfixCOnfiguration.com')
Port=587
SMTPSecure = 'tls'
Username = "one-of-my-gmail-email-id"
Password = "gmail-account-password"
SMTPOptions = array(
  'ssl' => array(
  'cafile' => '/etc/postfix/cacert.pem',
  'verify_peer' => false,
  'verify_peer_name' => false,
  'allow_self_signed' => true
)
```

#### As part of my troubleshooting, I did following:

1. In `/etc/mail/sendmail.inc`, un-commented the following by removing the prefix `"dnl #` use `/etc/mail/local-host-names`

   1. And, I do have list of my host-names in the `/etc/mail/local-host-names`
   2. executed the command : `$ make -C /etc/mail`
2. Edited `/etc/postfix/main.cf` with following values:

   ```
   mydomain = theDomainCreatedInPostfixCOnfiguration.com
   relay_domains = theDomainCreatedInPostfixCOnfiguration.com
   smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous,noplaintext
   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 TheIPaddressOfMyUbuntuMachineWifi
   relayhost = smtp.gmail.com
   myorigin = /etc/mailname
   myhostname = mail.theDomainCreatedInPostfixCOnfiguration.com
   smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
   ```

   1. In `/etc/mailname`, I have `mail.theDomainCreatedInPostfixCOnfiguration.com`
   2. In `/etc/aliases`, I have

      ```
      root: MyUsername-Of-Ubuntu-Login
      daemon: MyUsername-Of-Ubuntu-Login
      postmaster: MyUsername-Of-Ubuntu-Login
      ```
   3. I ran command: `systemctl reload postfix`
   4. I ran command: `sudo postmap /etc/aliases` , and built `aliases.db`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-modules
```

In /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd add these things
[Smtp.gmail.com]:587 gmailusername:gmailapppassword

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd sudo chown root:root /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db sudo chmod 0600 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd.db

Add below lines at end of main.cf
# enable SASL authentication
```

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication.
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption smtp_use_tls = yes
# where to find CA certificates smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

```
sudo service postfix restart

Hope your issue will resolve
```

Comment: Hi Laxman, Thanks. I verified, modified and ensured the parameters you mentioned, in my scripts. But, still the error persists.

Comment: Did you use app-password?

Comment: I think you are using FROM address like test@domain.com, but gmail not allowed. For troubleshooting use bellow command . echo "This is the message body" | mail -s "This is the subject" to@example.com -aFrom:sender@gmail.com and let me know